# Mat-select by formarray not showing selected value and options - Reactive forms Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have written below code so far to display the dropdowns. But selected value and options are not appearing in the dropdowns. Where I am doing wrong in the below code.

**Component code**

```
testForm: FormGroup;
get ctrls() {
  return this.testForm.get('ctrls') as FormArray;
}
data = [{
    initial: 'hen',
    options: ['hen', 'duck', 'parrot']
  },
  {
    initial: 'lion',
    options: ['lion', 'tiger', 'cheetah']
  }
];

constructor(private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    ctrls: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
    this.ctrls.push(this.formBuilder.control(this.data[i]));
  }
}
```

**Template code**

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
  <div formArrayName="ctrls" *ngFor="let animals of ctrls.controls; let i = index">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select [formControlName]="i" [(value)]="animals.value.initial">
        <mat-select-trigger>{{ animals.value.initial }}</mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let animal of animals.value.options" [value]="animal">{{ animmal }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

Please guide me in the correct way...

Please find the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-design-9dwawn) to check the issue

Comment: You have a typo: `animmal` --> `animal`, then it works

Comment: @rst that's fine, still selected value is not showing

Comment: Additionally, you should move all code in constructor to ngOnInit

Comment: @rst that's fine, I did that, still not displaying the value in mat-select

Comment: Checkout my answer, I changed the whole logic a little bit, hopefully you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the options from the controller, use the options from `data`.

Also, you need to initialise your formControl using the `this.data[i].initial`, since the data is the string, not the object.
I also changed the html a bit, using the controller instead of controllerName, since you already have a reference to it. I aslo removed the `[value]`-attribute in the `mat-select` because you are setting the value in the component. Using `[value]` is better suited for template driven instead of reactive forms, and using both may cause side effects.

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
  <div *ngFor="let animals of ctrls.controls; let i = index">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select [formControl]="animals">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let animal of data[i].options" [value]="animal">{{ animal }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

And in the ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group( {
   ctrls : this.formBuilder.array( [] )
 });
 for( let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++ ) {
   this.ctrls.push( this.formBuilder.control( this.data[ i ].initial ) );
 }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-design-q3wbah

EDIT:

After reading the comments, wanting to have an object as the data in the formControl, I would change the data, using something like this instead.

```
  data = [ 
    { options : [
      {name:'hen', icon: 'someIcon'},
      {name:'duck', icon: 'asd'},
      {name: 'parrot', icon: 'asdasd'} ] }
  ];
```

then, if you need to put in the correct initial object, I would match the name with your initial object, so you get the correct pointer. I have only selected the first element in the example below.

Then, you can use the `<mat-select-trigger>` as you initially wanted I believe.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-design-new-data

Comment: Thanks, got your suggestion. But I want to access another property from control, like icon of the selected option and value of the selected option, so need to pass object instead of string

Comment: Then, I would probably restructure your data, if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
animmal
```

Additionally, you should move the code form the constructor to the ngOnInit method

Check out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-design-m491ic?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Next, I believe you mixed up the `formControls`. I slightly changed the whole logic, hopefully you can use it.

Basically, the options need to go out of the `formcontrol`

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select
  [formControl]="animals"
  >
    <mat-option 
      *ngFor="let animal of data[i].options; let j = index"
      value="{{animal}}"
    >{{ animal }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And I changed the formgroup definition

```
this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group( {
      ctrls : this.formBuilder.array( [] )
    } );
    for( let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++ ) {
      this.ctrls.push( new FormControl({value: this.data[i].initial, disabled: false}) );
    }
```

Comment: This is working fine, but I want to pass the object for the value in the `FormControl` any suggestions?